# How fast is the continuum changing with respect to the relative change of size of the forcing notion?

Tags: set-theory

Has there been any research done on the related rates of forcing?

If I force to increase the size of the continuum $\mathfrak{c}$ by 5 $\aleph$'s, say from $\aleph_2$ to $\aleph_7$, how fast does the size of the notion of forcing $\mathbb{P}$ change from the ground model to the forcing extension?

It seems they must just have a constant ratio, but perhaps there are small forcings which have a very big effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if the following results are related, but they might be interesting:

Gitik an I have results, which simply say that (sometimes under the assumption of the existence of large cardinals) one can have a pair (W, V) of models of ZFC, such that adding an $Add(\omega, \kappa)$-generic over V, adds an  $Add(\omega, \lambda)$-generic over W, for some $\lambda > \kappa.$

Also, there are results by Shelah and Woodin that one can have
 a pair (W, V) of models of ZFC, such that W satisfies GCH, V=W[R], for some real R, and In V, the continuum is arbitrary large.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You say that the rates of change can vary wildly.

Comment: Do you have a citation for these results (especially the Shelah/Woodin one - that's wildly surprising to me)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber See (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274270?seq=1)[https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274270?seq=1]. Maybe even more interesting see [https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/killing-the-gch-everywhere-with-a-single-real/1F524FB6C7000BED4A7E16BE01AEE2B8](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/killing-the-gch-everywhere-with-a-single-real/1F524FB6C7000BED4A7E16BE01AEE2B8)

Comment: About result with Gitik, see three of my papers with him, available at http://math.ipm.ac.ir/~golshani/